# connect, send, and display data in Android via App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

I have a huge demand for people who want an application to connect to Uniquez from their Android devices.

I want to build an application to connect to my PHP and MySQL ShoutBox to send and receive information. First we need the user to be-able to login to the website. I am sure once I know how to do this I could use these techniques to send and receive shouts.

I do have access to Google's App Inventor and I have also downloaded and taken a quick peek at Eclipse. It seems App Inventor is a lot easier to use than Eclipse.

It all seems a little daunting and very complicated/

I do have knowledge in PHP and some JavaScript that could help me progress my knowledge.

Please could someone demonstrate how this could be done?

I want to learn this is why I am asking for help and not asking some one to do this for me.
I do need examples and a lot of help as I am totally new to building applications for the Android platform.

I am sorry I don't have any source code to go off right now as this is something I want to start building.

If you can do this in App Inventor this would be amazing. If not I will learn the hard way!
All information will be great full and I really am enthusiastic about completing my task.

Comment: I'm almost 100% percent you can't do that via App Inventor. You will have to learn the ahrd way :(

Comment: Can you give me some tips on how that can be done using other methods?

Comment: Hm.. Android development with the regular SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please find an example how to connect App Inventor with a MySQL database using a php script here http://ai.kittywolf.net/index.php/WebMysql (App Inventor Classic) and https://puravidaapps.com/mysql.php (App Inventor 2)

and here are more examples using App Inventor together with php scripts https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/app-inventor-developers-library/php

and here some App Inventor examples using embedded HTML/JavaScript http://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#javascript

for login to a webpage using App Inventor you also might want to look at this thread https://groups.google.com/d/msg/programming-with-app-inventor/FQSBZGcK1WE/CuUWZmEU5KkJ

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Please refer http://appinventorapi.com/app-inventor-php-application-framework/ for log-in framework and http://ai.kittywolf.net/index.php/PHP_TinyWebDB_with_MySQL for TinyWebDB to MySQL PHP Interface. I tried both, they worked well.